# Using both the project level and the app level static files in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have some static files that will remain common through all the application and I also have some static files that are specific to some particular apps only. Now in one of my apps, i want to use both the project level and the app level static files but that doesn't seem to work.
Following code section is from settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "homepage","static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "landing_page","static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

I have used `python manage.py collectstatic`
 and it returns with a warning which goes like **Found another file with the destination path 'homepage\css\style.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure
every static file has a unique path.**
Despite the above warning, I still get both the project level and the app level static files in the **staticfiles** folder in my root directory. When I use it in a template, the project level static file gets loaded while the app level static file (which is just a single CSS file) doesn't get loaded. Following is how I am trying to load the CSS file.

```
{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="{% static 'homepage/css/style.css' %}" href="PATHTOCSSHERE">
```

The developer tool of chrome also doesn't show the app level CSS file in the list of loaded files, which clearly means that the file doesn't get loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the template principle of putting your app-specific files inside another level of directory with the app name - for example `/project/homepage/static/homepage/css...`. Now your links will work (with your existing settings).

However unless you are actually distributing your apps independently, I don't find this a helpful way of organising things. Just use your project-level static directory, and have app-specific directories in there - `/project/static/homepage/css...`. Then you just need a single directory in STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: Sir, I have followed the convention for directory structure, just as you said. My app level static file resides in `/project/homepage/static/homepage/style.css` but it does not work as expected. Secondly, the later solutions seems a good option, but I wanted to keep my apps completely independent.

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely sorry everyone. Just saw an obvious mistake in my own code. The error has been resolved now. Thanks!